# How to create a UUID from both a "domain name" and an "object name"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, uuid

I must misunderstand either Python's **uuid** module, or [the RFC for generating UUIDs](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt)

How can you generate a UUID3 string using *both* a **domain name** and an **object name**?

I [see](http://www.minvolai.com/blog/2009/10/creating-universally-unique-id-in-python/) that "Version 3 UUIDs are generated from a qualified name space like an URL or a domain name and an object id or name."

However, at python.org is says the usage is [uuid.uuid3(namespace, name)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html). Since "namespace" here is supposed to specify the type of "name," how am I supposed to specify both "domain name" and "object name"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [section 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122.html#section-4.3) of the RFC:

> The version 3 or 5 UUID is meant for generating UUIDs from "names"
> that are drawn from, and unique within, some "name space".  The
> concept of name and name space should be broadly construed, and not
> limited to textual names.  For example, some name spaces are the
> domain name system, URLs, ISO Object IDs (OIDs), X.500 Distinguished
> Names (DNs), and reserved words in a programming language.

So UUID3 takes a namespace identifier (a UUID) and a name. Not a domain name and a object name. If you are using a domain name as the name, use the [`uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS` UUID](http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html#uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS).

Comment: Hmm... so "uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS" in combination with "a fully-qualified domain name" seems pretty useless unless you're expected to create "fake" labels, like "fakelabel.realdomain.com." - is that correct?

Comment: UUID3 is often used as a lookup key; a standardized hash, really.

Answer (score 0):

It is pertinent to add to the existing answer that version 3 or 5 UUIDs can be used to form hierarchies of identifiers simply by taking the result of one conversion and treating it as a namespace in another one. The proper way to generate arbitrary domain-specific identifiers is to first use the DNS namespace to arrive at "the" identifier for your domain, and then use that as a namespace (possibly recursively).

In pseudo-code, what you are looking for is `UUIDv3(UUIDv3(ns:DNS, "realdomain.com"), "your object name")`. As the owner of the domain, you have the right to pick whatever format of the name you want.

Another alternative is to form a URI for the object, such as `http://realdomain.com/objects/1`, and use `ns:URL` as the namespace. No need to devise your own hierarchy when there is already a ready-to-use one.